# Helly's theorem Test?

Tags: python-3.x, methods

I'm working on this following problem:

Method common_point: returns True if there exists a point that intersects all rectangles in the calling canvas. To test this (for axis parallel rectangles like ours), it is enough to test if every pair of rectangles intersects (according to a Helly’s theorem for axis-aligned rectangles: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly's_theorem

How would test Helly's theorum  in this case? Helly's theorem states that for N convex objects in D-dimensional space the fact that any (D+1) of them intersect implies that all together they have a common point. SO this means I have to check if any 3 rectangles intersect right? How would I do this??

So far I have:

```
def common_point(self):
    '''(Canvas)-> bool'''
    count=0
    for i in range(len(self.listofrectangles)-1):
        if self.listofrectangles[i].intersects(self.listofrectangles[i+1]):
            count +=1
    if count>=3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And when I run this I get True instead of False

```
>>> 
>>> c=Canvas()
>>> r1=Rectangle(Point(-2,-2), Point(-1,2), "blue")
>>> r2=Rectangle(Point(-2,-2), Point(2,-1), "blue")
>>> r3=Rectangle(Point(1,-2), Point(2,2), "blue")
>>> r4=Rectangle(Point(-2,1), Point(2,2), "blue")
>>> c.add_one_rectangle(r1)
>>> c.add_one_rectangle(r2)
>>> c.add_one_rectangle(r3)
>>> c.add_one_rectangle(r4)
>>> c.common_point()
False
```

Updated code:

```
 def common_point(self):
        '''(Canvas)-> bool'''
        TopRightx=[]
        TopRighty=[]
        BottomLeftx=[]
        BottomLefty=[]


        for i in self.listofrectangles:
            xval= i.bLx
            x2val= i.tRx
            TopRightx.append(x2val)
            BottomLeftx.append(xval)
            yval= i.bLy
            y2val= i.tRy
            BottomLefty.append(yval)
            TopRighty.append(y2val)

        if ((max(BottomLeftx))< (min(TopRightx))) and ((max(TopRighty))< (min(BottomLefty))):
            return True

        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding the theorem.  It is not sufficient that there be three independent intersections of two rectangles (that's absurd: imagine one additional rectangle, nowhere near the rest).  What the theorem says is that *every individual subset* of 3 rectangles must intersect, in order for the entire set to intersect.

The theorem doesn't seem to be a useful base for a computer algorithm, anyway, as enumerating all of the subsets of 3 out of n rectangles would take O(n<sup>3</sup>) time.  You can easily check for a common intersection with a single loop over all the rectangles: just keep track of the greatest left and top coordinates, and the least right and bottom coordinates.  If greatestLeft < leastRight, and greatestTop < leastBottom, there's an intersection (and those four coordinates give the exact bounds of the common area).

Comment: I still get False when I correct for this? How can the greatest top (y val) be smaller than the least bottom (y val) - I will edit my question with my updated code

Comment: I still get False when I correct for this? How can the greatest top (y val) be smaller than the least bottom (y val) - I edited my question with my updated code

Comment: I was assuming that the Y coordinate increases towards the bottom of the canvas, as is common in computer graphics.  If you're using the mathematical convention of the Y axis pointing up, just swap 'top' and 'bottom' in what I said.